# Unable to style wtform attributes

Tags: html, css, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

Respected Members,

The .py file has the following:

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, session, redirect, url_for
    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
    from wtforms import StringField,SubmitField
    from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'kmykey'
    
    class SimpleForm(FlaskForm):
        username = StringField("Username:", validators=[DataRequired()])
        password = StringField("Password:", validators=[DataRequired()])
        submit = SubmitField("Submit")
    @app.route('/', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
    def index():
        form = SimpleForm()
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            session['username'] = form.username.data
            session['password'] = form.password.data
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        return render_template('Login_Page.html', form=form)
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run()
```

The corresponding jinja template consists of:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ticket Booking</title>
    <link rel= "stylesheet" type= "text/css" href= "{{ url_for('static',filename='Login_Page.css') }}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div align="center" class="main1">
    <form method="POST">
      <h1>Railway Booking Portal</h1>
      <h2>Welcome!</h2>
      <br>
      {# This hidden_tag is a CSRF security feature. #}
      {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
      {{ form.username.label(class_='uname') }} {{ form.username(placeholder='email here') }}
      <br>
      {{ form.password.label(class_='passwd')  }} {{ form.password() }}
      <br>
      <a class="abc" href="Sign_Up.html"><u>SignUp</u></a>
      <br>
      <a class="abc1" href="Password_Reset.html"><u>ForgotPassword</u></a>
      <br>
      <br>
      {{ form.submit() }}
      <br>
      <p>"One's destination is never a place, but a new way of seeing things." - Henry Miller</p>
</form>
</div>
```

I'm successfully able to connect HTML with css and background image can be seen when app is run thru Flask, however, username & password labels/fields are not getting formatted. The css file consists of the following:

```
    body{
      background: url(railway-tracks.jpeg);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    h1{
      color: black;
    }
    p{
      font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
      font-size: 200%;
      color: black;
    }
    .uname{
      display: inline-block;
      min-width: 90px;
      color: red;
    }
    .passwd{
      display: inline-block;
      min-width: 90px;
      color: red;
    }
```

Kindly guide what is the part that I'm missing or using it incorrectly?

Thank you

(Updated)

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
class_='uname'
class_='passwd'
```

but style for:

```
.username{}
.password{}
```

The class names should match

**UPDATE after OP edit**

You haven’t added the class declarations to the labels. You added them to the fields.  Try:

```
{{ form.username.label(class_='uname') }} {{ form.username(placeholder='email here') }}
{{ form.password.label(class_='passwd')  }} {{ form.password}}
```

or try:

```
{{ form.username.label, extra_classes='uname' }} {{ form.username(placeholder='email here') }}
{{ form.password.label, extra_classes='passwd'  }} {{ form.password}}
```

It works:

[image: It works:]

Comment: Hi, both names are the same on my editor, however when I was pasting it here I changed it to differentiate css class name from wtforms' attributes. I've updated my query. Kindly guide why the styling is still not working? What is the possible broken link?

Comment: Hi, first of all, thanks very much for helping me out. Unfortunately, I'm still not abe to change the color of those labels. In the css file, I'm setting the inline-block to keep both input fields down to each other which are scattered, but unable to do so. I've just edited the files to show what exactly I'm using. I sincerely appreciate your guidance on this matter. Regards

Comment: Ot could be that your css file is invaid.  `background: url(rail.jpeg);` should be `background: url("rail.jpeg");`

Comment: Respected Member, I'm able to successfully connect html with css file, i.e. the background image is already working when an application runs thru flask on the localhost. My sincere apologies for extending this naive issue, but I'm having a hard time getting hold of the problem/loophole. I'm including the entire code to give a clear picture, I'll be thankful for your kind and generous help. Regards

Comment: Hi, as instructed I made a change to jinja templating, this is the error I see "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got '='". I tried to google the error to see what possibly went wrong, but haven't figured out yet. Any insight will be very much appreciated. Regards

Comment: I made a project using your updated code. Other than the bg image (which I don't have), it works!  Please check for typos in your code.  See my project structure at the right in the image.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for running it. The directory structure as shown on the screenshot is similar to what I have. May I know what are the contents of __init__.py file in the main dir? I don't have __pycache__ folder yet since I haven't setup the DB and added models to it. Respected Sir/Mam, I just copied the code shared by me at the top, I didn't work. I tried to add/remove spaces around '=' in jinja templating but nothing. "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of print statement', got '='".

Comment: Anyways, I'll see what blunder is being done by me. Thanks very much for your kind help. Take care. Regards